# How to add a column to a table based on data from table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas to extract data from a csv file to print out a table. This is the code I have so far

```
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
        df_filter= df[['Time','ID','ItemName', "PassFailStatus"]
        if df_filter['PassFailStatus'].str.contains('Fail').any():
            finalTable= df_filter[(df_filter.PassFailStatus == 'Fail')]
            if finalTable.empty:
                print("Did not complete")
                sheet1[cellLocLastRow('A')] = "Did not complete"
            else:
                fullFinalTable= finalTable[['Time','ID','ItemName']]
                finalTableFilter = fullFinalTable.to_string()
                print(finalTableFilter)
                lastRow = writeTableToExcel(sheet1, "A", lastRow, fullFinalTable, 'Time') #prints to excel
        else:
            print("Run Successful")
            sheet1[cellLocLastRow('A')] = "Run Successful"
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")
        sheet1[cellLocLastRow('A')] = "File does not exist"
```

[image: The output looks like this]

However I want to add a Fix column, where if the ID column says a certain string, then it will print out something in the Fix column. For instance if the string "Integration" was found in ID column, the the fix column will say "Check folder" as shown in the photo.
[image: Output with added column]
When I try to add another column, I get errors, any help would be greatly appreciated!

The following table is what I currently have

```
Time         ID                   ItemName
2020-Aug-07  Integration_comp_14  Integration_System::CheckTest_eos0
2020-Aug-07  Integration_comp_14  Connections_SYSTEM::System_eos0
2020-Aug-07  Integration_comp_9   System::SourceTestExternal_eos0
2020-Aug-07  MainInstrument_2017  Integration::FunctionalTest_eos0
2020-Aug-07  MainInstrument_2020  Integration::TimingLoopbackOddTest_eos0
2020-Aug-07                       Integration::TimingLoopbackEvenTest_eos0
2020-Aug-07  MainInstrument_2022  Integration::TimingLoopbackOddTest_eos0
```

The following is the table I am trying to get

```
Time         ID                   ItemName                                 Fix
2020-Aug-07  Integration_comp_14  Integration_System::CheckTest_eos0       Folder
2020-Aug-07  Integration_comp_14  Connections_SYSTEM::System_eos0          Folder
2020-Aug-07  Integration_comp_9   System::SourceTestExternal_eos0          Folder
2020-Aug-07  MainInstrument_2017  Integration::FunctionalTest_eos0         Device
2020-Aug-07  MainInstrument_2020  Integration::TimingLoopbackOddTest_eos0  Device
2020-Aug-07                       Integration::TimingLoopbackEvenTest_eos0 None
2020-Aug-07  MainInstrument_2022  Integration::TimingLoopbackOddTest_eos0  Device
```

Comment: The code references columns that are not contained in the sample data `"PassFailStatus", "Counters"`

Comment: `"PassFailStatus"` was used to filter the table, so it is not in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Fix Column you can use a combination of numpy and pandas.

Numpy - you can use np.where to do your "case when then else" part
Pandas - you can do df.str.contains('string')

To put them together, it would be

```
df['Fix'] = np.where(df['col'].str.contains('string'),'something','something else')
```

You can even put multiple statements - think of it like a nested if statement in excel

```
df['Fix'] = np.where(df.str.contains('string'),'something',np.where(df.str.contains('string'),'something','something else') )
```

Here is a working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
columns=['a','b','c']
rows=['1','2','3']
d_base=np.array(['no','yes','hello'])
data=np.tile(d_base,(3,1))

#create df
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns,index=rows)
```

[image]

'

Lets create a new column called Fix that looks for a string in the column and gives it a category

```
df['Fix'] = np.where(df['a'].str.contains('no'),'something','something else')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary to map substrings to their values:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Integration_comp_14', 'MainInstrument_2017', 'Integration_comp_14']})

replace_map = {'Integration': 'Folder', 'Instrument': 'Device'}
df['Fix'] = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join([replace_map[y] for y in replace_map if y in row.ID]), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    ID     Fix
0  Integration_comp_14  Folder
1  MainInstrument_2017  Device
2  Integration_comp_14  Folder
```